# Error while using apt-get update

Tags: apt

When I tried using apt-get i get the following error:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install gdm
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1.0: cannot open 
shared object file: no such file or directory
```

and not just with gdm:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1.0: cannot open 
shared object file: no such file or directory
```

as far as my operating system no clue how to find that info (ubuntu 17.04) i think

Comment: Please include the output of sudo `find / -name libbz2.so.1.0` in your answer.

Comment: Please see my answer. Please remember to vote/accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm encountering this on WSL after encountering a BSOD while performing `sudo apt-get -y full-upgrade`. I get an error that libbz2 cant be opened while using `dpkg -i` after downloading the appropriate package.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

for keeping your Packages up-to-date. Try

```
sudo apt-get purge gdm
```

for deleting the package with all attached files and then use

```
sudo apt-get install -f gdm
```

For installing all again.

Comment: That would be `gdm3`. Also ask the user to edit their subject title.

Comment: You can edit them yourself @heynnema. And I did suggest an edit, but I don't know why it wasn't used.

Comment: I edited the question's body, and if you re-read it now, you'll see that `sudo apt-get update` **and** `sudo apt-get install` don't work, so I don't think your answer will work. They're missing `libbz2-1.0`.

Comment: @heynnema I realized that myself and currently am searching for a way to solve this to improve my answer :).

Comment: If we find the location where they can manually download the missing .deb file, they may be able to install it with `dpkg -i` or `gdebi`. Then apt-get *might* work again.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libbz2-1.0

Comment: It might be that only the link of that library is missing. I suggested him to search for it. If I'm right just creating one should solve his problem. @heynnema

Comment: ok I found this file 'libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-5 i386.deb' now how to install it?

Comment: @maxx Please include the output of sudo `find / -name libbz2.so.1.0` in your answer.

Comment: sudo dpkg -i '/media/maxx/lego/ubuntu_17/libbz2-1.0.6-5_i386.deb' it seemed to work, but now I have no software center, hmm

Comment: found the problem, 32 bit software loaded, need to load 64 bit software, a TOTAL SYSTEM SHUT DOWN, thank you all for the help.

Comment: ok I downloaded a ubuntu 17.04, reinstalled and now back to no wifi, I see the connections, it only connects for a few seconds then disconnects, " gksu -H gedit /etc/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf" does not work, it says 'gksu' is currently not insalled, then says unable to locate package gksu. Does 17.04 not come with these packages? or do I need to find them in ubuntu 17.04 and unpack them, ( because as soon as I upload and install a package, it seems as if another package is missing or goes bad, it is a never ending loop of download a package and go bad, until ubuntu stop working).

Comment: < lspci -knn | grep Net -A2> <br/> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]

Comment: network manager file not found    sudo nano /ect/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

`sudo apt-get` fails because you're missing `libbz2-1.0` (and maybe more).

Go here https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libbz2-1.0 and **download the correct version for your system**.

To remove the wrong version (32-bit):

```
sudo dpkg -P libbz2-1.0.6-5_i386
```

To install the correct/downloaded version (64-bit):

```
sudo dpkg -i libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-8.1_amd64.deb # this is for zesty 64-bit
```